# In XPages the Extension Library "listInline" command gives us a vertical instead of a horizontal list

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

We are having an issue with Extension Library "listInline" command gives us a vertical instead of a horizontal list in Xpages. Below is the code and a snap shot of the issue:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xp:label value="Here is an inline list:" id="label4"></xp:label>
    <xe:listInline id= "listInline1">
        <xp:link escape= "true" text= "Link 1" id= "label1"></xp:link>
        <xp:link escape= "true" text= "Link 2" id= "link2"></xp:link>
        <xp:link escape= "true" text= "Link 3" id= "link3"></xp:link>
    </xe:listInline>
</xp:view>
```

Gives us

```xml
Here is an inline list:
Link 1
Link 2
Link 3
```

Instead of the links going across the page.

```xml
Link 1 Link 2 Link 3
```

Comment: I see no code. Am I missing something?

Comment: Update your post with at least a snippet of the code of what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

It shows entries in vertical list if you use **theme "Bootstrap4"**.

Add following css to get a horizontal list:

```css
.lotusInlinelist li {
    border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 7px;
}
```

As an alternative, you could switch to another theme like "Bootstrap3".